# saving object to IsolatedStorage in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, serialization, json.net

I have a class structure with properties below:

```
    public string Artiste { get; set; }
    public string Featuring { get; set; }
    public JObject RegionName { get; set; }        
    public JArray Seasons { get; set; }
```

The problem is that I want to save an instance of this class to an IsolatedStorage, I added the `DataContract` attribute to the class and `DataMember` attribute to each property but I got an error that `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue` cannot be serialized. How can I serialized and save a complex object like the above?

Comment: RegionName is a Json Object and Seasons a Json Array

Comment: yes, but why? Because it looks like it should be a string.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some types cannot be serialized, you must avoid such types while serializing. You can mark `[IgnoreDataMember]` for the members that you dont want to serialize or to the members that cannot be serialized.